# Properly exit all processes Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have an Erlang "backend" that contains a lot of processes. Now I'm preparing a benchmark file that will run  atest for latency, and I would like to run this test inside of a loop that would increase certain load parameters.

I basicly have a `server:init()` function that starts up the main server manager process, and then I register `N` clients on the server through that manager. The manager will appoint an arbitrary data actor process to the newly registered client.

Each of these data actors have multiple clients. I have added a small diagram to show you what I mean.

```
       +------------+
       |Manager     |
       +------------++-----------+
          +       +              |
          |       |              |
          v       v              v
       +-----+  +-----+       +-----+
       |     |  |     |       |     |
       | Da 1|  | Da 2|       |Da N |
       +-----+  +-----+ . . . +-----+
           +         +
           |         |
           |         |
           |         |
 +----+    | +----+  |
 |c1.1|<---| |c2.1|<-|
 |    |    | |    |  |
 +----+    | +----+  |
           |         |
 +----+    | +----+  |
 |c1.2|<---+ |c2.2|<-+
 |    |      |    |
 +----+      +----+
 .           .
 .           .
 .           .
```

What I want to do now is run the server and kill all the processes when my load test is done. It seems to be so that I can't run my loadtest twice in the same `erl` repl because some processes are still running. (register(name, ) fails for example).

I read about killing processes [here](http://www.erlang.org/erldoc?q=file&x=0&y=0), but it would seem odd to me that in a language like Erlang there is no more galant way to do this.

What I can make up from that file is that my `manager` will have to send a signal to all data actors to kill theirselves, but before doing that, kill all their client processes as wel? I.e., spread the message and start killing processes from the bottom of my tree upwards to my manager.

It seems very verbose, and I'm wondering if there is an other way.

So far I have the following:

When my loadtest is done the process (shell) that initiated the manager process does this:

```
exit() ->
    unregister(data_actor_manager),
    unregister(shell),
    exit(data_actor_manager, normal).
```

But this results in a nasty error:

```
 {"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erlang,unregister,[data_actor_manager],[]},{server_single_actor,exit,0,[{file,"c:/Users/CHRIST~1/DOCUME~1/BITBUC~1/ERLANG~2/src/server_single_actor.erl"},{line,48}]},{load,start,0,[{file,"c:/Users/CHRIST~1/
CUME~1/BITBUC~1/ERLANG~2/src/load.erl"},{line,36}]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]}}
```

The error would imply that `data_actor_manager` is not a valid name or Pid but it is..

So I tried the following. Thinking that I might not have to unregister the atom associated with the manager Pid I tried this:

```
exit() ->
    exit(whereis(data_actor_manager), normal).
```

But again, I get a `badarg` error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Erlang/OTP supervisor behavior seems very suited to this problem: http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html and http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html

Basically you can set up a supervision tree which will cascade down from your main server and handle the killing and restarting of your clients.

Comment: Alternatively, just `link` all your processes.